# jQuery dialog content not displaying

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#records').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="records" title="Results">
    Content to Display
</div>
```

The dialog box appears without any content. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/WGhHm/) - perhaps you have multiple `div`s with the same `id` ???

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ4LZ/. I would imagine the content is being cleared elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Have you tried this in js fiddle?

Comment: You can try inspect your code with firebug or your favorite browser's DOM inspector to see what is actualy going wrong. Without the whole page nobody can answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me - see this http://jsfiddle.net/rqf3t/ but this has no css. I imagine the problem must be the css you are using - you don't have a `<p>` tag around Content to Display (which the samples on the jQuery site do) so I wonder if the CSS is hiding the content. Try

1) Adding a `<p>` tag around your content, as in the example

2) Using firebug or similar to see if "Content to Display" is actually there, but hidden by CSS.

Comment: Yep! My bad. I had a similar tag with visibility hidden

Answer (score 0):

Something is definitely amiss, because your code works fine for me. Here's what I used with all the bits and pieces put together:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jqueryUI/ui-lightness/query-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#records').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="records" title="Results">
    Content to Display
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified your jquery-ui.css then this may happen because it happened to me and I just replaced the original jquery-ui.css and it was fine